# How do I find the angle between tension and the tangent to a string?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

> Consider a loop made of a string of length $L$ an has a linear mass
>   density $\sigma$. If the loop is rotating with an angular frequency $w$
>   around an axis passing through the centre and perpendicular to the
>   plane of the loop, what is the tension on the string?

Note that we are in the empty space and there is no external force acting on the system.

I started by taking a $\mathrm{d}L$ element on the loop. Since that $\mathrm{d}L$ element is doing circular motion, it will have a central acceleration, so the radial components of the tension forces that are applied to both sides of the $\mathrm{d}L$ element must be equal to $m \omega^2 R$, where $R$ is the radius of the loop. But how do I find the angle the tension force makes with the tangent line at that point?

Comment: I vote to reopen. This does show effort and is about a physics concept.

Comment: Tension is parallel to the tangent. You need to consider two adjacent elements of length $dL$. The tangents at the ends are not parallel. The sum of the tension forces is not 0.

Comment: The tension in Newton per sq. m is d(rw)^2 where d is spcific mass of the string. This can be seen by drawing two radians a small angle x apart together with their tangents.  Where these intersect their combined length closely approximates the small lengt of string between the two radians. These semitangents also form the sides of a parallelogram, the diameter of which is proportional to the centripetal force while the sides are proportional to the tensile force. The rest is simple geometry using sinx = tgx =x when x is sufficiently small.

Comment: Agree - should reopen.

Comment: @Jens I couldn't understand what you mean exactly.Is there any chance that you can draw the general structure ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a homework/exercises site. For recommendations of other sites see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/). You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com/.

Comment: @sammygerbil Then why is there a 'homework/exercise' tag in the site and almost none of the questions in that that are closed ?

Comment: @Leth The reason we have the tag is that some people don't want to see any questions relating to homework assignments, self-study problems, exercises, etc. The reason few of the questions in it are closed, if that is indeed the case, is that (1) it is possible to ask a question related to a homework problem or exercise, and (2) perhaps many which _are_closed have been deleted so you don't see them. I've made an edit which may push your question over the line into being conceptual.

Comment: @DavidZ Ok, thanks for both explanation and the editing.